# How To Replace DaggerAppComponent During Hilt Migration - Android Dependency Injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

***EDIT/CLARIFICATION:***

I'm using the [Hilt Migration Guide](https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide), and since there are many moving parts and custom pieces of the app I'm using AggregatorEntryPoint to migrate one piece at a time, as indicated in the Migration Guide.

If I'm reading the guide correctly, the @HiltAndroidApp annotation doesn't come in until the very end of the migration, once all of the dagger elements have been removed.

---

I'm migrating our app from Dagger 2 to Hilt. I'm fairly new to all of this and having a very tough time.

In the `BaseApplication` I'm trying to replace the AppComponent, which is currently built with the `DaggerAppComponent` builder.

There are references to the `AppComponent` all over the codebase, so I'm not sure how to remove/replace this functionality.

### BaseApplication.kt

```
open class BaseApplication : Application() {
    
    ...

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent
        private set

    ...

    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(this))
            .build()

    appComponent.inject(this)
}
```

### AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, NetworkService::class, AnalyticsModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun providesNetworkService(): NetworkService

    fun inject(activity: MapActivity)
    fun inject(viewModel: NetworkBaseViewModel)
    fun inject(application: BaseApplication)
    fun inject(contactsDataSourceFactory: ContactsDataSourceFactory)
    fun inject(contactDetailViewModel: ContactDetailViewModel)
    fun inject(contactDetailFragment: ContactDetailFragment)
    fun inject(contactDetailEditFragment: ContactDetailEditFragment)
    fun inject(contactDetailCreateFragment: ContactDetailCreateFragment)
    fun inject(contactsListViewModel: ContactsListViewModel)
    fun inject(activityFeedViewModel: ActivityFeedViewModel)
    fun inject(httpService: BaseHttpService)
    fun inject(httpService: BaseWebService.ClientWrapper)
    fun inject(pdfViewerFragment: PDFViewerFragment)
    fun inject(commuteTimeManager: CommuteTimeManager)
    fun inject(verifyLoginWorker: VerifyLoginWorker)
    fun inject(loginWebFragment: LoginWebFragment)
}
```

***Here's where the problem starts.***
I updated the AppModule by annotating it with `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` and replacing the parameters with `@Inject constructor()`.  According to the errors, the constructor on a Module must be empty.

### AppModule.kt

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) // <- Added
@Module
// class AppModule(private val application: BaseApplication) { // <-Removed
class AppModule @Inject constructor() { // <- Added

    // Old Code:
    // @Provides
    // @Singleton
    // fun provideApplication(): BaseApplication  = application

    // @Provides
    // @Singleton
    // internal fun provideContext(): Context = application

    // New Code:
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(@ApplicationContext application: BaseApplication): BaseApplication {
        return application as BaseApplication
    }

}
```

Now in the `DaggerAppComponent` builder I have an error:

`Too many arguments for public constructor AppModule() defined in com.companyname.db.dependencyinjection.AppModule`

```
appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule(this)) // <- Here is the error
                .build()
```

If I can't add a constructor to `AppModule`, how am I supposed to work around this?

** **Note:** I am trying to migrate the app piece by piece since there are a lot of moving parts here, which is why I haven't removed the `AppComponent` altogether.  Maybe there's something I'm missing in there though.  I've been following along the migration guide and have experimented with adding/removing the aggregator entry point.

### Example of use of `AppComponent`
NetworkBaseViewModel.kt

```
open class NetworkBaseViewModel (application: Application): BaseViewModel(application) {

    ...

    init {
        @Suppress("LeakingThis")
        (application.applicationContext as? BaseApplication)?.appComponent?.inject(this@NetworkBaseViewModel)

    ...
}
```

Comment: the error you're getting is because you're passing an argument to the module constructor when it doesn't take one, not necessarily related with the rest of your setup

Comment: @takecare I understand the error. I am not certain how to go about replacing the `DaggerAppComponent` with an AggregatorEntryPoint to begin the migration.

Comment: @n_r Unfortunately, no. I had to focus on other issues and never came back to this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this when using Hilt:

```
appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
    .appModule(AppModule(this))
    .build()
```

All you have to do is to annotate your Application class with `@HiltAndroidApp`. Since your BaseApplication is `open`, I assume you'd have to do it in the Application class that extends it.

You also don't have to do this in your NetworkBaseViewModel:

```
(application.applicationContext as? BaseApplication)?.appComponent?.inject(this@NetworkBaseViewModel)
```

Now you just annotate your ViewModel with `@HiltViewModel` and when you want to inject something into your ViewModel, you annotate the constructor with `@Inject` and make it's dependencies injectable (either by constructor injection or with [Modules](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#hilt-modules)). For example:

```
@HiltViewModel
class NetworkViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val retrofitService: ExampleRetrofitService
) : ViewModel() {

    // ViewModel stuff

}
```

Also your AppModule doesn't even need a constructor with `@Inject` annotation because you don't inject anything into it. See the example Module [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#inject-provides), it's just an `object`.

Finally, I recommend reading this guide -> [Dependency injection with Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Hilt Migration Guide?  I'm migrating things stepwise with an aggregator entry point.  The @/HiltAndroidApp doesn't appear to come into play until the end of the migration.  I have tried your approach, but without migrating the entire app in one whole swoop, this throws a large amount of errors in the rest of the app.